# SSL validation through CNAME issue namecheap

Tags: ssl, cname, namecheap

I am trying to validate SSL certificate on NAMECHEAP for subdomain.
I have added DNS record A type for DNS in advanced DNS settings and subdomain is working.
Now I created a SSL certificate in AWS for my subdomain and added CNAME record in NAMECHEAP advanced DNS settings. But its been more than 2 hours and its not been validated.

My question is there something special that needs to be done for sub domain, main domain SSL validation worked just fine.